# How to filter for any day of the week in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, datetime, filter, odoo

**For example:** I need to filter tasks for "Monday" and i don´t know how to do it.
I have tried in several ways but I can´t find the solution.

I done it for "Last Week" and "This Week":

```
<filter string="Last Week" name="last_week" separator="1"
        domain="[('date', '&gt;=', ((context_today()+relativedelta(weeks=-2, days=1, weekday=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))),
               ('date', '&lt;=', ((context_today()+relativedelta(weeks=-1,weekday=6)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))]"/>

<filter string="This Week" name="this_week" separator="1"
        domain="[('date', '&lt;=', ((context_today()+relativedelta(weeks=0, days=7, weekday=-1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))),
               ('date', '&gt;=', ((context_today()-relativedelta(weeks=1, weekday=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))]"/>
```

Anyone with any idea? And sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on your question while also looking for a solution to this problem. I am not sure if it is related, but even if it does not it might help other people.

This is my solution to get a filter for a certain day in the past. If you want to filter all data of a monday and today it is saturday than this solution should work for you.

```
('create_date','>=',(context_today()-relativedelta(days=(context_today().weekday()-A), weeks=B)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), 
('create_date','<',(context_today()-relativedelta(days=(context_today().weekday()-A))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

where:

A = weekday nr. (i.e. mon=0, tue=1, etc)

B = weeks you want to go back. (remove if it is same week)

So if you want to get the data of last week Monday this should work:

```
<filter 
string="Last Week" 
name="last_week" 
separator="1"
domain="[('date','&gt;=',(context_today()-relativedelta(days=(context_today().weekday()-0))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), 
        ('date','&lt;',(context_today()-relativedelta(days=(context_today().weekday()-0))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"
/>
```

Hope it helps and that it works.